# How to load data onScroll in ReactNative with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i want to load data from my realtime database, but only 15 entries everytime, because the database is huge. The database has a name of the vocable and got information about it like translations and stats. I want to sort it alphabetic by the value "wordENG", but there is a problem, when i use orderByChild like this:

```
database()
    .ref(`vocables/${UID}`)
    .orderByChild("wordENG")
    .startAt(requestCount)
    .limitToFirst(15)
    .once("value")
    .then(snap => {
        console.log(snap.val());
    })
```

When i try to use startAt, to get the data on scrolling, i get the problem that startAt need to be a string, so a word of the database list. I don't want to store this word everytime and search for new one after that, but currently i cannot see another way. Is there a way to get data alphabetic on scrolling with a number to count or do i need to realize it with saving the last word and search from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination with Firebase queries work based on knowing the anchor item, not on offsets. So you will need to indeed know the `wordENG` value of the node to start at (or start after with the relatively new `startAfter` method), and possibly the key (if there may be multiple child nodes with the same `wordENG` value.

If you're new to Firebase, I recommend also reading some of the previous [questions about pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20pagination), as this comes up regularly.

Comment: Hello Frank, thanks for your answer, but startAfter is only in firestore available, or why can i not use or find them?

Best Regards
DreamGamer

Comment: `startAfter` calls were added to Realtime Database a few months ago (see [JS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startafter) for example). If they didn't make it to the React Native Firebase library yet, you might want to post a feature request to its repo. But with or without that new method, you'll need to know the anchor item to implement pagination.

Comment: Yes i think so! First of all, i can't find startAfter in RNFirebase but startAt also worked. I hope i did it like you mean it. I think with anchor item you mean the last item that was loaded, so my current solution is [this](https://pastebin.com/VCaahAjj). It's now loading on and on, but is this really the simplest way?

Comment: Using `startAt()`/`startAfter` is not inherently more complex than using an offset counter, you may just have to get used to it. It is the idiomatic way to paginate with Firebase, and any other cursor-based pagination system. If you can think of a simpler way within the such an API, I'm quite sure folks would love to see an example of that.